# Tailwind and Alpine.js flicker

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css, alpine.js

How do I fix flickering on tailwind and alpine.js? Already added x-cloak as per [alpine.js](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/cloak) . But still not fixed.

> If the "default" state of an x-show on page load is "false", you may
> want to use x-cloak on the page to avoid "page flicker" (The effect
> that happens when the browser renders your content before Alpine is
> finished initializing and hiding it.) You can learn more about x-cloak
> in its documentation.

style.css (uncompiled)

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

[x-cloak] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My Site</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

    <script src="js/alpine.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body class="bg-gray-50 font-sans flex flex-col min-h-screen">
    <header class="sticky top-0 z-50">

      <nav class="bg-white shadow">
        <div x-data="{ isOpen: false }" @click.outside="isOpen = false">
          <div class="container px-6 py-3 mx-auto">
            <div
              class="flex flex-col md:flex-row md:justify-between md:items-center"
            >
              <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                <div class="flex items-center">
                  <a
                    class="text-2xl font-bold text-gray-800 transition-colors duration-200 transform lg:text-3xl hover:text-gray-700"
                    href="/"
                  >
                  Logo
                    <!-- <img
                      src="logo.png"
                      alt="logo"
                    /> -->
                  </a>

                  <!-- Search input on desktop screen -->
                  <div class="mx-3 md:mx-10 md:block">
                    <div class="relative">
                      <span
                        x-cloak
                        class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3"
                      >
                        <svg
                          class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-400"
                          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                          fill="none"
                        >
                          <path
                            d="M21 21L15 15M17 10C17 13.866 13.866 17 10 17C6.13401 17 3 13.866 3 10C3 6.13401 6.13401 3 10 3C13.866 3 17 6.13401 17 10Z"
                            stroke="currentColor"
                            stroke-width="2"
                            stroke-linecap="round"
                            stroke-linejoin="round"
                          ></path>
                        </svg>
                      </span>

                      <input
                        type="text"
                        class="w-full py-2 pl-10 pr-4 text-gray-700 bg-white border rounded-md"
                        placeholder="Search"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Mobile menu button -->
                <div class="flex md:hidden" x-cloak>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-600"
                    aria-label="toggle menu"
                    @click="isOpen = !isOpen"
                    x-cloak
                  >
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="w-6 h-6 fill-current">
                      <path
                        fill-rule="evenodd"
                        d="M4 5h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 1 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm0 6h16a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H4a1 1 0 0 1 0-2z"
                      ></path>
                    </svg>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Mobile Menu open: "block", Menu closed: "hidden" -->
              <div
                :class="isOpen ? 'block' : 'hidden'"
                class="items-center md:flex"
                x-cloak
              >
                <div
                  class="flex flex-col mt-2 md:flex-row md:mt-0 md:mx-1"
                  x-cloak
                >
                  <a
                    class="my-1 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:text-cyan-700 hover:underline md:mx-4 md:my-0"
                    href="/"
                    >Home</a
                  >
                  <a
                    class="my-1 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:text-cyan-700 hover:underline md:mx-4 md:my-0"
                    href="/page"
                    >Page</a
                  >
                </div>

                <div class="flex items-center py-2 -mx-1 md:mx-0" x-cloak>
                  <a
                    class="block w-1/2 px-3 md:px-5 py-2 md:py-3 mx-1 text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-center text-gray-700 transition-colors duration-200 transform rounded md:mx-2 md:w-auto border shadow"
                    href="#"
                    >Login</a
                  >
                  <a
                    class="block w-1/2 px-3 md:px-5 py-2 md:py-3 mx-1 text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-center text-gray-100 transition-colors duration-200 transform bg-cyan-600 rounded hover:bg-cyan-700 md:mx-0 md:w-auto border border-cyan-600 shadow"
                    href="#"
                    >Register</a
                  >
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <main></main>
  </body>
</html>
```

I even tried to record it.

[image: screen recording]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this in production or development mode?

Comment: This is happening in both environment. But it show much in development.

Answer (score 6):

How big is your style.css bundle file? Try dropping

```
<style>
[x-cloak] {
  display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

directly into the `<head>` above your style.css import and see if that fixes it. If that doesn't fix it, I would probably start looking at the waterfall for that CSS bundle file in the devtools **Network** > **CSS**. If you're bundle is big, keep in mind it wont block rendering of what's in the body.